# Understanding Arduino - Reading in from the serial port in Java

Tags: java, arduino

I'm trying to get the [Arduino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino) to communicate with my computer using a simple Java program. Say if a button is pushed on the Arduino then it'll send a message to my Java program then it'll preform some task based on that. What I'm having issues with is reading the serial input from the Arduino. What is this process or where to get more information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Interfacing/Java) and [this tutorial](http://silveiraneto.net/2009/03/01/arduino-and-java/).